# Coding Comma Delimited in the data

Tags: excel, vba

This is the data set I get with the code

[image: This is the data set I get with the code]

Here is the code below:

```
Sub GetStockPrices()

'Convert dataset to comma delimited format
 With Sheets("Historical Prices").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"),DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, OtherChar _
    :=",", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End Sub
```

Data set that I want

[image: Data set that I want]

The problem is

> Convert dataset to comma delimited format

If any can help with this issue I have been stuck for like 3 days. I apologize in advance this is my first time posting in stackoverflow. Any questions to clarify?

Comment: What exactly is "the problem" you have?  What happens when you run that code, and how is it different from what you expect?  Maybe you don't need both `Comma:=True` *and* `OtherChar _:=","`  ?

Comment: What does your data initially look like? What are your Decimal, Thousands, List, and Date separators? You can retrieve them by using the `Application.International` property.

Comment: If you wan to convert the data from one format to another, you could use the text to columns feature in excel with comma as the separator. If you're asking something else, I don't understand what "the problem" is.